# print input data from a file

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a text file name input.txt with data -

[ANB] 33 34 48 85 50 59 Anniston,AL

[AUO] 32 40 11 85 26 24 Auburn,AL

[BHM] 33 34 11 86 45 0 Birmingham,AL

Here all I have to do print this line but I can't Here is my source code can anyone please tell me what I am doing here wrong

```
int main()
{
string a,b;float c,d,e,f,g,h;
int z,q;

string i[15], j[15];
float  k[15], l[15], m[15], n[15], o[15], p[15];//size of array more than number of entries in data file
float x[15], y[15];



ifstream infile;
infile.open("input.txt");//open the text file

if (!infile)
{
    cout << "Unable to open file";
    exit(1); // terminate with error
}
z=0;
while (!infile.eof())
{
//To make three arrays for each column (a for 1st column, b for 2nd....)

infile>>a>>b>>c>>d>>e>>f>>g>>h;

    i[z]=a;
    j[z]=b;
    k[z]=c;
    l[z]=d;
    m[z]=e;
    n[z]=f;
    o[z]=g;
    p[z]=h;

    x[z]=k[z]+l[z]/60+m[z]/3600;
    y[z]=n[z]+o[z]/60+p[z]/3600;

    cout<<i[z]<<"\t"<<k[z]<<"\t"<< l[z]<<endl;

    z++;
}
 // To print 1st entry (1st row), similarly we can print any row
infile.close();
//getch();
```

}

And I am new in c++ any kind of suggestion will be helpful

Comment: What do you mean you can't? It sounds like you have a problem but you're not describing what it is.

Comment: The main problem it becomes an infinite loop and print the first line only what's the solution of the problem can you please tell me

Comment: The first problem is that you're not initializing `z` to zero, so you're getting Undefined Behavior when using it to access the array indicies.

Comment: @0x499602D2 there's `z=0;` right in front of the loop

Comment: @Hasan based on your sample input shouldn't it be `infile>>a>>c>>d>>e>>f>>g>>h>>b;` instead of `infile>>a>>b>>c>>d>>e>>f>>g>>h;`

Comment: @petert isn't it the same but somehow it works. But main problem is now in this txt there is 1200+ data but it shows only 15 data then programm execute what's the problem can you please tell??

Comment: @Hasan you declared `string i[15]`, so 15 it is. If you want the size to be dynamic, use something like a `std::vector`

Comment: @PeterT Ya I want to practice vector after this program. Can you please explain me how's it work infile>>a>>c>>d>>e>>f>>g>>h>>b; instead of infile>>a>>b>>c>>d>>e>>f>>g>>h; I think it means the same thing aren't it??

Comment: @Hasan the order matters, your input is "string int int int int int int string" so doing `infile>>string>>string>>float>>float>>float>>float>>float>>float;` is different from `infile>>string>>float>>float>>float>>float>>float>>float>>string;`

Comment: Oh Now I get it. Now I can have a sound sleep :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to avoid the infinite loop is the `std::getline()` function.
Instead of `infile>>a>>b>>c>>d>>e>>f>>g>>h;` you can use this:

```
string tmp;
stringstream ss;
getline(infile, tmp);
ss << tmp;
```

and after this you can split the line as you want. For e.g.: `ss >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e >> f >> g >>h;` or 
 `ss >> i[z] >> j[z] >> k[z] >> l[z] >> m[z] >> n[z] >> o[z] >> p[z];`

You will need an extra header file to use stringstream: `#include <sstream>`.

Comment: Thank you for your solution but I already get one above thank you very  much for helping me :)